# Make section and subsection titles similar to journal

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I would like to make the titles of the sections of my paper and subtitles, have the same formatting as the American Economic Review. Here's [an example](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/michael.weber/research/pdf/stickyPrices.pdf):

[image]

The section titles should be centered, start with I, II, III, and subsections with A, B, C ...

While they do provide [a `.cls` class](http://www.aeaweb.org/templates/latex_templates.zip), I cannot figure out which lines I should put in my preamble as I would like to avoid using the whole thing. Does anyone know which lines should suffice and modifications needed (if any?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\usepackage{titlesec}%

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalsize\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape\filcenter}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}

\section{A Delightful Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A Lovely Subsection}
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bernard, thanks for the reply. This is almost what I am looking for. The only thing is that if one adds another section and subsection to the text, the subsection indexing does not restart. I.e. a subsection of section II starts being numbered at B. 

How can I solve that?

Comment: @phdstudent: It's my fault: I copy-pasted the redefinition of `\thesection` to redefine `\thesubsection`, but forgot to change the name of the counter accordingly. The code has been fixed. Thank you for pointing it!